# jQuery Unexpected token - in append option

Tags: javascript, jquery

Code:

```
$('#Sub_categories').append($("<option/>", {
    value: element['ID'],
    text: element['English_name'].toLowerCase(),
    class: 'ucwords'
    data-GST: '1'
}));
```

Error in

> data-GST

How can I append data attribute by using this method?

Comment: You forgot a comma after the value for the `class` property.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the `,` between the last two key/value pairs, and the `-` in the key is being interpreted as a mathematical operation. To fix this you need to place it in quotes:

```
$('#Sub_categories').append($("<option/>", {
  value: element['ID'],
  text: element['English_name'].toLowerCase(),
  class: 'ucwords',
  'data-GST': '1'
}));
```

Comment: #Rory McCrossan You are awesome guy. Thank you.

Comment: No problem. Don't forget to accept an answer if it helped